# moving shape from previous worksheet to current worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a grouping of 20 chevron shapes, used to identify how far into the spreadsheet you are. Users start on tab 1 the first chevron is coloured, and continue along. On tab 15, 15 chevrons are coloured, and on tab 20, all 20 chevrons are coloured.

I have tried identifying the previous active worksheet, but I constantly get errors. Users can jump from tab 1 to 5 to 10, or from tab 20, to 5 to 13.
As a result, I cannot use the .previous command.
I have tried using a global variable in lieu with the worksheet deactivate to get the lastWS name, as I feel this is the best method, but to no avail.
IE
this is my global variable

```
Public lastWS As Worksheet
```

To change chevron colours, which works fine, I call when the worksheet is activated

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Call chevronColours(1)
End Sub
```

on each worksheet I have this to recognize the last used worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_DeActivate()
  Set lastWS = ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

and my module code is:

```
Sub chevronColours(k As Integer)

Dim r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer, i As Integer
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set currentWS = ActiveSheet
lastWS.Shapes("Group 2").Cut
wbk.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Select
wbk.ActiveSheet.Paste

For i = 1 To 19
  If i <= k Then
    currentWS.Shapes("Chevron " & i).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
  Else
    currentWS.Shapes("Chevron " & i).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End If
Next i

End Sub
```

In this scenario it says that the item with the specified name was not found. Using the debugger I found this to be because when using the deactivate procedure, my lastWS become the current worksheet.

What can I do to use the previous worksheet in this way?

Comment: Rather than `Set lastWS = ActiveSheet` try `Set lastWS = Me`.  Also, I guess you have the Activate and Deactivate events in all workssheets?  You could do it with a single instance of `Workbook_SheetActivate` and `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` in the `ThisWorkbook` module (in which case you would use `Set lastWS = Sh` )

Comment: This is the correct solution, I didn't realise that you could do it all in the workbook section. Many thanks. Add it as a comment and I will give it the green tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `Set lastWS = ActiveSheet` use `Set lastWS = Me`.

Also, I guess you have the `Activate` and `Deactivate` events in all workssheets?

You could do it with a single instance of `Workbook_SheetActivate` and `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` in the `ThisWorkbook` module

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set lastWS = Sh
End Sub
```

Also, your `chevronColours` Sub could be passed the workbook, like this

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    chevronColours Sh
End Sub
```

and defined as

```
Sub chevronColours(currentWS As Worksheet)
```

I think you will find there are a few other issues with your `chevronColours` code.  Here's your code refactored

```
Sub chevronColours(currentWS As Worksheet)
    Dim k As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim g As GroupObject

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = Selection
    lastWS.Shapes("Group 2").Cut
    currentWS.Paste
    Set g = Selection
    rng.Select
    g.Name = "Group 2"
    With currentWS.Range("B2")
        g.Top = .Top
        g.Left = .Left
    End With
    k = currentWS.Index
    If g.ShapeRange.GroupItems.Count = currentWS.Parent.Worksheets.Count Then
        For i = 1 To g.ShapeRange.GroupItems.Count
            g.ShapeRange.GroupItems(i).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(i <= k, vbGreen, vbWhite)
        Next i
    Else
        ' Sheets vs chevron count mismatch
        '  what now?
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Storing References to the Worksheets

What I did was use `Static ChevronList As Object` reference an ArrayList. The worksheet names are added to the ArrayList.   `ArrayList.IndexOf_3(Worksheet.Name)` returns the zero based Index of the worksheet name.

[Better Soulutions - Static Variables](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/variables/static-variables.htm)

> Variables do have a lifetime.
>   Indicates that the local variable is preserved between calls.
>   A static variable can be thought of as a local variable with memory.
>   A static variable is a local variable whose lifetime is the lifetime of the entire module and not the procedure where it is declared.
>   In fact static variables retain their values as long as the code module is active. There does not have to be any code running all the time.
>   Therefore a static variable has the scope of a local variable but the lifetime of a module level variable.

### Working with Shapes

You should give the group a meaningful name.

> ```
>  ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group 2").Name = "Chevron Group"
> ```

Passing an array on names to the `Shapes.Range()` property returns a `ShapeRange` of of all the shapes in the array.  Using the `ShapeRange` to modify the properties of a group of shapes is more efficient then changing them individually.

### Workbook Events

As Chris Neilsen mentioned use the  `Workbook_SheetActivate` instead of the `Worksheet_Activate` events of the individual worksheets.  I recommend also recommend calling the subroutine from the `Workbook_Open` event.  The `Workbook_Open` fires after the user has enabled the content.  If the user opens the workbook, changes worksheets, and then enables the content

> ```
> Private Sub Workbook_Open()
>     MoveChevronGroup ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
> End Sub
> ```

[image]

---

I didn't bother using the last worksheet to track the location of the group.  Searching 20 sheets for the group is virtually instantaneous and will prevent possible bugs.

---

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Const DebugMode = True

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    MoveChevronGroup ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal sh As Object)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MoveChevronGroup sh.Range("B2")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub MoveChevronGroup(Optional Destination As Range)
    Const GroupName As String = "Chevron Group"
    Static ChevronList As Object
    Dim ChevronGroup As Shape, ws As Worksheet
    Dim results() As Variant
    Dim ChevronCount As Long, n As Long
    If ChevronList Is Nothing Then Set ChevronList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ChevronGroup = ws.Shapes(GroupName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ChevronGroup Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next

    Set ws = Destination.Parent

    If Not ChevronGroup.Parent.Name = ws.Name Then
        ChevronGroup.Cut
        Destination.Parent.Paste
        Set ChevronGroup = ws.Shapes(GroupName)
        ChevronGroup.Left = Destination.Left
        ChevronGroup.Top = Destination.Top
    End If

    If Not ChevronList.Contains(ws.Name) Then ChevronList.Add ws.Name
    ChevronCount = ChevronList.IndexOf_3(ws.Name) + 1

    If DebugMode Then Debug.Print "ChevronList.Count: "; ChevronList.Count, "ChevronList.IndexOf_3(ws.Name) + 1: "; ChevronList.IndexOf_3(ws.Name) + 1

    ReDim results(ChevronCount - 1)
    For n = 1 To ChevronCount
        results(n - 1) = n
    Next

    If DebugMode Then Debug.Print "Results Array Values: "; Join(results, ",")

    ChevronGroup.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ChevronGroup.GroupItems.Range(results).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End Sub
```

Modified code to add the Shape Index instead of the Shape Name to the results().  There seems to be a bug using the shape names. I am going to ask SO about the bug.  Because of the change the Chevroons need to be added to the group in order.

[Download Chevrons Demo.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Enq0klsBhK38N73zN2y16NN35UPUwmcy). The main code is in the Workbook's code module.  The code for prepping the workbook, adding sheets and Chevrons, are in the `PrepWorkbook` module.

Comment: Interesting solution, and I say this as someone who is learning, thus it is nice to see something different. Regarding Static Variables, what are you doing with the chevronlist? I cant follow it properly. Also, why not use static variables all the time, this way the values can always be remembered? Is more memory used/performance affected by having statics?

Comment: @TejkaranSamra The memory usage is the same as normal.  Obviously if you assign 2G of data to a static variable it will slow things down.  Static variables have the same problems as Globals.  Say you have `Sub A` and `Sub B` and they both are using the same static variable or global `X`,  cane either `Sub A` or `Sub B` be confident of the state `X`.  Does `X=10` because `Sub A` assigned 10 to it or did `Sub B` assign the value?

Comment: @TejkaranSamra `ChevronList` is used to track the `Worksheet.Names` and the order, in which, they were activated.  For example: the workbook is opened the `ActiveSheet.Name` (say `"Sheet1"`) is added to the  `ChevronList`, then `"Sheet2"` is click it is added, then  `"Sheet5"`.  `ChevronList.IndexOf_3(ws.Name)` returns the 0 based Index of the `ws.Name` in the collection.  So `ChevronList.IndexOf_3("Sheet1")` will return 0 because it was the first name added, `ChevronList.IndexOf_3("Sheet2") = 1`, `ChevronList.IndexOf_3("Sheet5") = 2`.

Comment: Ok, so a static variable is a locally defined global one? Ill do my research on that, as I feel it is something I should get to know. I tried your method in a new workbook, but it says that ChevronGroup.Parent.Name causes an error. Not sure why? Additionally, could you tell me where the previous worksheet comes into play, I don't really see where it falls in / I love notes on my code

Comment: I updated my code, adding some `Debug.Print` messages and fixing a bug (an anomaly) and a download link.

Comment: That is brilliant, got it all working, thank you very much!